# popout a mac mail window from full screen / split view

Tags: mail.app, email, macos, split-view

I run my mac mail in split view with other programs on a side monitor. Sometimes it would be nice to pop out reply windows and individual emails from full screen / split view so I can bring them to my main monitor.

Is there anyway to do this without undocking the mail program all together?

Answer (score 2):

I asked Apple support about this one. The representative didn't seem to think that this was a supported feature in current OS X (El Capitan) and passed it along as a feature request.

The only other workaround I can think of is right-clicking Mail in the Dock to open a new viewer or new message on your primary display. This works for me when I have Mail in full-screen in an off-screen space. I haven't tried it on a dual-monitor setup yet.

Answer (score 0):

1. Reason

the reason seems to be this [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/368609/370922)

2. Solution

I tried everything out. The only thing works for me is to "**minimise**" Mail.

3. **Trick**

Because I normally close an app by shortcut `command+w`, It's so annoyed to minimise Mail every time.

So I added a shortcut to close Mail using `command+w`.
World is much better then.

System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcut -> App Shortcuts -> +.

(I guess you know the next already)
[image]