# Prevent Mail pop up automatically when there's a new email

Tags: mail.app, mojave

I'm using macOS Mojave. Apparently I've changed a setting - but can't figure out which one - that forces Mail to automatically pop up in the active desktop when there's new email.

For instance, I'm in a desktop with Safari maximized, I receive an email and the Mail app automatically splits the screen and shows the new email.

This happens even when I'm connected to a projector and in a meeting. considering I've even turned on the Do Not Disturb mode *when mirroring TV and projectors*, it's super strange.

Could you please help me find this option to prevent Mail pop up when there's a new email?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344223/mail-app-keeps-popping-up-in-the-background-in-mac-os-mojave

Answer (score 1):

IF you go to Notifications > Mail you should be able to change the Mail Alert Style to "None" to avoid mail alerts altogether.

Source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4306641

Comment: Thanks Darison. I need those banners. I just don't want the Mail application to pop up and take up my desktop. as long as it stays in the desktop it was, showing notifications is fine.