# Mail app Keeps opening, can't find notification options on google calendar

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, mail.app, google-calendar

I know, there are a lot of peoples asking this, and I followed every single guide, but I REALLY DO NOT found the "calendars link" and so I can't keep following the guide...Has google changed the layout or something else, I don't know.
But I really need to fix this mail problem, even apple support has said to me "There is no solution for this problem at the moment, keep your macbook up to date".
Really thanks to those that can help me.

Comment: Welcome to Apple.SE!  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour]. I myself asked the same question a while ago and found another asked even some more time ago. So if any new answers are there, I feel they would go to those questions and they should answer your query too. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344223/mail-app-keeps-popping-up-in-the-background-in-mac-os-mojave/361509#361509 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361383/mail-app-opens-randomly-in-macos-10-14-5

Comment: As for your question, Go to https://calendar.google.com, the gear-shaped icon-> notifications and then edit the settings. I think this is what you meant by "do not find calendar link"